# pass data between UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview, pass-data

Leveraging `RESideMenu` https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu in my app, now has an issue of passing some `urlString` related to lists in `sideMenuViewControll` to show its web page in right `UIWebView`.

Original codes like below:

```
case 2: {
    navigationController.viewControllers = @[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"]];
    [self.sideMenuViewController hideMenuViewController];
}
    break;
```

`"second"` is for `secondViewController` that has a `UIWebView` for showing web page at right side. `secondViewController` has a property: `urlString`.

My intention is to show its web page when selecting "Profile". Tried several way, however, I can't find one to set `urlString` after `navigationController.viewControllers = @[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"]];`

How can I set and pass `urlString` so that it could be used like `NSUrl * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all import your secondViewController in your first View Controller's .m file

Create in secondViewController's .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) *NSString passedURL;
```

Then give the storyboard name in Attribute Inspector.
Now, on button event of profile or whatever

```
secondViewController *svc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];
svc.passedURL = urlString;
[self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Thats it. Hope that it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

The Below line shows that,

navigationController.viewControllers = @[[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"]];

You are trying to access the array of ViewControllers, but I am not sure why you want all the ViewControllers. I think you can get the secondViewController like this below and set the string

```
 secondViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondViewController"];
    secondViewController.urlString = urlString;
```

Answer (score 0):

After tried every method I could get, find a workaround by using `[navigationController.viewControllers[0] setTitle:urlStrings]` might works.

Is doing such correctly?